# How to find certain text on child nodes using JavaScript when selecting by class name

Tags: javascript

I have multiple divs with the same structure as follows, I need to check for a text within the child nodes on each main div tag

```
<div class="s4-wpcell-plain">
  <div class="ms-chrome">
    <div class="ms-chrome-title" id="WPWPQ6_ChromeTitle">
      <span title="My Content" id="WPTitleWPQ6" class="js-wp-titleCell">
        <h2 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-wp-titleText">Results (0)</h2>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div wpid="50348231-8acb-4794-af32-d481915fc127" haspers="false" id="WPWPQ6" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody ms-WPBorder noindex ms-wpContentDivSpace " allowdelete="false" style="">
      <div style="display: none;">
      </div>
        <div componentid="ctl00_ctl40_g_50348231_8acb_4794_af32_d481915fc127_csr" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_50348231_8acb_4794_af32_d481915fc127_csr">  
          <div class="containerForStyle">   
            <ul class="cbs-List">                   
              <div class="ms-srch-result-noResults">There are no items to show.&nbsp;</div>     
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case I'm selecting the main div with `document.getElementsByClassName("s4-wpcell-plain")` from there I need to check for the text "There are no items to show" and hide the corresponding main div.

I have tried to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("s4-wpcell-plain").getElementsByTagName("*")
```

and after this, I will scan on each element on `innerText` but it is not getting the elements, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, not a `Node`, so you can't call `getElementsByTagName` on it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Comment: Is the main div `.s4-wpcell-plain` or the div that has the text? Are there more than one of these texts to be found? Are there multiple `.s4-wpcell-plain`?

Comment: Mate, you can proceed like: `var eles = document.getElementsByClassName("s4-wpcell-plain");`

`eles.map((ele) => { if(ele.innerText.indexOf(TemplateString) !== -1) {ele.style.display = 'none';} });`

Comment: There are more divs like this one, I'm selecting them with getElementsByClassName so I have a list and from there I guess I need to loop into the child nodes until find the element that contains the text, which is in <ul><div> tag

Comment: Are writing the JavaScript in the display template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you wanted `.s4-wpcell-plain` to disappear or the element that has the text so I wrote code for both objectives and commented out the part that hides `.s4-wpcell-plain`.

Trying to find a text in DOM is inefficient, you need to use whatever this widget uses and I can assure you it isn't the text it generates. The pattern looks like if there's *no items to show* the message would be in a div with the className of:

```
.ms-srch-result-noResults
```

I don't know how your widget works so I'm assuming that whenever there's *no items to show* then it creates:

```
<div class="ms-srch-result-noResults">There are no items to show.&nbsp;</div>
```

The Demo:

- Collects all `.ms-srch-result-noResults` into a NodeList with **[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**
- Makes that NodeList into an array with **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**
- Runs the array thru **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** array method.
- On each `.ms-srch-result-noResults` is sets `style.display` to `none`

---

- There's also an alternate `forEach()` method setup to use **[`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)** to find `.s4-wpcell-plain` and then hide that instead.

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

```js
/* Collect all .ms-srch-result-noResults into a NodeList
|| then convert that NodeList into an array
*/
var noResults = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ms-srch-result-noResults'));

/* Run the array thru forEach() method
|| hide each .ms-srch-result-noResults
*/
noResults.forEach(function(v, i) {
  v.style.display = 'none';
});

/*//Or do the same thing but hide the .s4-wpcell-plain instead 
noResults.forEach(function(v, i) {
  var main = v.closest('.s4-wpcell-plain');
  main.style.display = 'none';
});
*/
```

```html
<div class="s4-wpcell-plain">
  <div class="ms-chrome">
    <div class="ms-chrome-title" id="WPWPQ6_ChromeTitle">
      <span title="My Content" id="WPTitleWPQ6" class="js-wp-titleCell">
        <h2 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-wp-titleText">Results (0)</h2>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div wpid="50348231-8acb-4794-af32-d481915fc127" haspers="false" id="WPWPQ6" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody ms-WPBorder noindex ms-wpContentDivSpace " allowdelete="false" style="">
      <div style="display: none;">
      </div>
      <div componentid="ctl00_ctl40_g_50348231_8acb_4794_af32_d481915fc127_csr" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_50348231_8acb_4794_af32_d481915fc127_csr">
        <div class="containerForStyle">
          <ul class="cbs-List">
            <li class="ms-srch-result-noResults">There are no items to show.&nbsp;</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="cbs-List">
          <li class="ms-srch-result-results">There are items to show.&nbsp;</li>

          <li>ITEM</li>
          <li>ITEM</li>
          <li>ITEM</li>
          <li>ITEM</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="cbs-List">
        <li class="ms-srch-result-results">There are items to show.&nbsp;</li>
        <li>ITEM</li>
        <li>ITEM</li>
        <li>ITEM</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="cbs-List">
      <li class="ms-srch-result-noResults">There are no items to show.&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerText` returns text content of all of its nested childrens

try:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("s4-wpcell-plain");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerText.indexOf('There are no items to show') !== -1) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }   
}
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'IndexOf' of undefined when running the code

Comment: @CarlosM since `getElementsByClassName ` returns list, you have to iterate. check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

So here are the things you may follow,

1 - Get the list of elements with `document.getElementsByTagName` 
2 - You can use iterate over, to filter out with the `innerText` && `ClassName` for each element

**CODE:**

```
// Get the elements list by ClassName
var allEles = documents.getElementsByTagName("*");
var templateString = 'Something';
var wantedClassName = 'ClassName';

// Iterate over all the elements
for(var key in allEles) { 
    if( (a[key].className === wantedClassName) && (a[key].innerText) === templateString ) {
        /* Do Whatever you want with this element => a[key] */
    }
}
```

`